# Doing an npm install and it says fatal error: 'dbus/dbus.h' file not found. Where can I find this file?

Tags: node.js, qt, compilation, npm, dbus

I was having issues with node and npm so I completely uninstalled them and reinstalled them. A preliminary search indicates this should be in usr/include. I did delete files from there during uninstall and I'm worried I may have mistakenly deleted this one as well.

Where can I find the file?

Operating System: OSX 10.11.3

Node version: 5.5.0

npm version: 3.5.3

Here is the error message I receive:

```
 CXX(target) Release/obj.target/dbus/src/dbus.o
../src/dbus.cc:6:10: fatal error: 'dbus/dbus.h' file not found
#include <dbus/dbus.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/dbus/src/dbus.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 15.3.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.5.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/crhistian/Four51/OrderCloud- Seed:Components/seed-development-submodule/node_modules/dbus
gyp ERR! node -v v5.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN install:dbus@0.2.17 dbus@0.2.17 install: `node-gyp configure build`
npm WARN install:dbus@0.2.17 Exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install dbus (and its development files/headers) via whatever package manager you use. For homebrew it should be something like `brew install d-bus`.